# How do I move a group of items in a PHP array below the next group of items?

Tags: php, arrays

In an Array with normal numerical keys ( `$file_array_for_editing` ), I want to move a set of consecutive X number of values below the next set of X values.

Example: If a group of X values is 10, then in an Array of 50, I have 5 sets of 10 values. I want to move the 10 values in set 3 - below the 10 values in set 4.

So that : Set1(10 values) , Set2(10 values) , **Set3**(10 values) , **Set4**(10 values) , Set5(10 values)

Becomes: Set1(10 values) , Set2(10 values) , **Set4**(10 values) , **Set3**(10 values) Set5(10 values)

Since I don't know a better way, this is how I have done it now - by what I believe is switching the values:

```
$file_array_for_editing = [];
for($i=1; $i <= 50; $i++) {
    $file_array_for_editing[] = $i;
}

$number_in_one_set = 10 ;
$set_number_to_move = 3 ;

$f = $file_array_for_editing ;
$s = ($set_number_to_move - 1) * $number_in_one_set ; // (3 - 1) * 10 = 20 

list(
  $f[$s+0],$f[$s+1],$f[$s+2],$f[$s+3],$f[$s+4],$f[$s+5],$f[$s+6],$f[$s+7],$f[$s+8],$f[$s+9],$f[$s+10],$f[$s+11],$f[$s+12],$f[$s+13],$f[$s+14],$f[$s+15],$f[$s+16],$f[$s+17],$f[$s+18],$f[$s+19]
) =
[$f[$s+10],$f[$s+11],$f[$s+12],$f[$s+13],$f[$s+14],$f[$s+15],$f[$s+16],$f[$s+17],$f[$s+18],$f[$s+19],$f[$s+0],$f[$s+1],$f[$s+2],$f[$s+3],$f[$s+4],$f[$s+5],$f[$s+6],$f[$s+7],$f[$s+8],$f[$s+9]];

$file_array_for_editing = $f ;
```

At the end, the numerical keys stay properly in order, from 0 to 49.
I need help finding a way to do this where I can vary the `$number_in_one_set`

If possible, I would appreciate help finding a solution where it is clearly apparent what is being done, so that after a year, when I look at the code again, it will be easy to understand. (as in, even now, I just vaguely understand why the `list()` above works)

Comment: If all your groups have the exact same size, then I’d start with `array_chunk`, and then combine the resulting arrays again in the new order.

Comment: For clarity, please share a (sample of) the source array, and expected result. Use `var_export($sourceArray)` to facilitate reproduction.

Comment: The array could be represented by the numbers 1 to 100 : `$array = array(''); for ($i = 0; $i <= 100; $i++) { array_push($array, "$i"); }` - should i edit the question to include this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly following might help you on your way. You can change the 'sets' you'd like to switch using array `$switch`.

```
<?php
$arr = [];
for($i=1; $i <= 50; $i++) {
    $arr[] = $i;
}

$set = 10; // each set has 10 items
$switch = [3, 4]; // switch element 3 vs. 4

$newArr = array_chunk($arr, $set); // chop array in chunks of size $set

// swap
$tmp = $newArr[$switch[0]]; // $temp=$newArr[3]
$newArr[$switch[0]] = $newArr[$switch[1]]; // $newArr[3]=newArr[4]
$newArr[$switch[1]] = $tmp; // $newArr[4]=$newArr[3]

$result = [];
array_walk_recursive($newArr, function($el) use (&$result) { $result[] = $el; }); // flatten array
```

EDIT

[`array_walk_recursive()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) applies the callback function (`function($el)`) to each element of nested array `$newArr`.
Each element of array `$newArr`, referenced by `$el` will be pushed into array `$result`, a flat indexed array.

Also, because the anonymous function (closure) writes to flat array `$result` which is defined in the parent scope, we need to employ the [`use`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) language construct.

source [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php): *Closures may also inherit variables from the parent scope. Any such variables must be passed to the `use` language construct.*

working [demo](https://3v4l.org/V1omP)

Comment: jibsteroos - that seems to work perfectly! I understand that the "array_chunk" has to be flattened. Could you explain how the last line starting: `array_walk_recursive(` does this?

Answer (score 0):

@jibsteroos - I really like the method you provided (which @CBroe also suggested) - reason being that it allows any two sets anywhere within the original array to be swapped.

After some thought, I find I prefer using the method below, even though it is a little long winded - reason being my use case is only to exchange a set with the one below it.

```
<?php
$arr = []; // Setting up a sample array
for($i=1; $i <= 50; $i++) {
    $arr[] = $i;
}

$set_size = 10 ; // 10 items per set
$set = 3 ; // set to move down
$set_to_move = ($set - 1) * $set_size; // start position of this set in the array - 20

print_r($arr) ;
echo '<hr>';

$slice1 = array_slice($arr,0,$set_to_move);
print_r($slice1) ; // from the start of the array - to the start of the set to move
echo '<hr>';

$slice2 = array_slice($arr,$set_to_move,$set_size);
print_r($slice2) ; // the set to move
echo '<hr>';

$slice3 = array_slice($arr,$set_to_move + $set_size,$set_size);
print_r($slice3) ; // the set after the set to move
echo '<hr>';

$slice4 = array_slice($arr,$set_to_move + (2 * $set_size));
print_r($slice4) ; // the rest of the array
echo '<hr>';

$arr_edited = array_merge($slice1,$slice3,$slice2,$slice4,);
print_r($arr_edited) ; // All 4 arrays combined in the new order
echo '<hr>';
```